# How to tell if tasks is master task or subcall/dependency in Phing

Tags: phing

My idea is to make my Phing script talk, but I would like them to talk only once I've run the called task. Does anyone knows one to tell inside a Phing task if it's the parent caller or not ?

Sample build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="my_project" default="install">

    <target name="install" depends="configure, migrate">
        <!-- I would like to call this only if `phing install`-->
        <phingcall target="talk" />
    </target>

    <target name="configure">

        <!-- I would like to call this only if `phing configure`-->
        <phingcall target="talk" />
    </target>

    <target name="migrate-database">
        <!-- I would like to call this only if `phing migrate-database`-->
        <phingcall target="talk" />
    </target>

    <target name="talk">
        <property name="message" value="Phing deployment operation done" override="true" />
        <echo msg="${message}" />
        <exec command="say '${message}'" />
    </target>

</project>
```